# Failure to detect Python path to install packages on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I install a python package (like virtualenv and django )in my ubuntu and it cant find the location in my ubuntu path.

What can i do for it ?

for example i write `pip install virtualenv`
and then my terminal has answer

```
 WARNING: The script virtualenv is installed in '/home/famirqfr/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your Python path. (which you can find using `which python`)

The warning says that `virtualenv` binary is at that directory

> is installed in '/home/famirqfr/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.

To fix this, edit your `~/.bashrc`

Add/ensure you have  a line like

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

or...

> if you prefer to suppress this warning, use `--no-warn-script-location`

---

This is really only useful if you want to run `virtualenv` as its own command rather than like `python -m virtualenv new_env`

---

Alternatively, Python3 comes with `venv` pre-installed, so you don't need to separately install `virtualenv`

`python -m venv new_env`